# Way to check Backbone.history has already been started?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Is there a way to check whether `Backbone.history` already have been started or not.

I am consuming a view as a service which is written using Backbone and routers.
When I am rendering the view I am getting the error `Backbone.history has already been started`.

Is there a way to avoid the error?

Because of this error the routers attached in the external view is not invoked.

Comment: `Backbone.history.started` gets set after you start it.

Comment: hi thanks for you insigh. There is not such variable for backbone

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`Backbone.History.started` is a boolean variable that indicated whether or not History has been started. Be sure that the `H` is uppercase.